How do I import a module I made into my JS code that is a script in HTML?
I want to import a module that I made
Okay so I made a simple little thing to test it that doesn't really DO anything except confirm if it works...which it doesn't.
here's my "module" (testmodule.js):
export class Test {
    static printTest() {
        console.log("it works");
    }
}

I added a line in my HTML file importing it as a module
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="testmodule.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

and then I tried using the function in my js (script.js):
Test.printTest();

and that gave me the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
 http://0.0.0.0:8000/script.js:1
so I tried importing it in my script. updated script.js:
import Test from "moduletest";
Test.printTest();

and that gave me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
I also tried writing the import command a different way I don't remember what that was but it gave me that same error

Script that use import are also considered modules. Add the type="module" attribute to your script.js tag.

Besides that, you need to either import Test like this: import { Test } from 'testmodule.js' or change the export to a default: export default class Test.

You do not need the <script> tag for testmodule.js, since that script already gets imported by script.js !

So this error stems from a very common programming paradigm: Libraries. Basically we move code that concerns "that" thing into a file of its own and when we need it, we include it. Thankfully JS finally included this feature, although libraries are known as modules in JS. But not really as you would expect.
First of all, you can't reference a module from a non-module script. Take the following:
<script type="module" src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>

If b.js references (imports) anything from a.js, that's an exception, even though we include a.js as a module. Both a.js and b.js must be modules in order for that to work.
That's because modules are not available to the global scope. They are included in what JS calls script scope. You can see it in your dev-tools if you stop executing with debugger and then have a look at the source tab -> script. So taking the example from above:
<script type="module" src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>

b.js (global scope) has no clue about the existence of anything in a.js (script scope). So basically, if you want to work with with functions/classes/methods outside of their module, you'll need to import that module and include that properly in your HTML:
<script type="module" src="b.js"></script> <!-- b.js imports from a.js -->  

Here's the MDN

You can actually do something like this:
MODULE:
    // filename: test.module.mjs
    globalThis.MyPublicStuff =
    {
        Welcome: 'Hi! Welcome to my site.'
    }

COMMON:
    // filename: test.common.js
    document.addEventListener
    (
        'readystatechange', Event =>
        {
            if ( document.readyState == 'complete' )
            {
                const MyPublicStuff = globalThis.MyPublicStuff;
                
                console.log(MyPublicStuff.Welcome);
                // Output: Hi! Welcome to my site.
            }
        }
    )

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   
   <head>
      <script src="test.module.mjs" type="module"></script>
      <script src="test.common.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
   </body>
   
</html>

NOTE: When using stuff from other script that populates the DOM and/or globalThis (at least one) then it's needed to wait for that specific script to load. This can easily be achieved by listening to the readystatechange event on the document.
You can also assign everything exported from a module to the global context like in the script below.
// Import the module itself.
import ThisContext from import.meta.url;

// After everything is exported, then this will be executed once.
ThisContext.then
(
  MODULE =>
  {
    // Assign each exported component to globalThis.
    for ( const Component in MODULE )
    {
      globalThis[Component] = MODULE[Component];
    }
  }
);


The whole idea of modules is that we do NOT want global stuff floating around on window.... ?

@Kokodoko, I agree with you. But you have to notice that the question demands this answer. The intention, if I'm not wrong, is to expose something from a module to be accessible in a common JavaScript context.

you need to set up some few thing, 1st an import map in your html file, generally you better want it in the head
<script type='importmap'> { "imports": { "KeyWord": "./path/to/what/you/need/to/import" } } </script>
then use that keyword to import in both your html script, AND, the file that script is pointing to
